# Infinite power of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, matrix-calculus

Consider a matrix that satisfies

$$ \bf M =  {\begin{bmatrix} \bf A ^\top & \bf B ^\top \end{bmatrix}}
            {\begin{bmatrix} \bf A \bf A ^\top + \bf C \bf C ^\top &
                            \bf A \bf B ^\top \\ 
                            \bf B \bf A ^\top &
                            \bf B \bf B ^\top \end{bmatrix}}^{-1}
            {\begin{bmatrix} \bf A \\ \bf B \end{bmatrix}} $$

where $\bf A$, $\bf B$, and $\bf C$ are matrices as well. I am attempting to calculate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\bf{M}}^n$$

Notice that if ${\bf C} = {\bf 0}$ this would be trivial, since then ${\bf{M}}^n={\bf{M}}$ for all $n$. I have tried using the block matrix inversion formula to explicitly invert the middle matrix but I was not able to obtain the result that way. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the block-matrix inversion formula and simplifying, it follows that

$$ \bf M =  \bf E+(E-I)D(E-I), $$

where

\begin{align}  
\bf D \equiv & \; \bf A^{\top}(A(I-E)A^{\top}+BB^{\top})^{-1}A,\\
\bf E \equiv & \; \bf  C^{\top}(CC^{\top})^{-1}C.
\end{align}

Notice that $\bf E$ is idempotent. Therefore,

$$ {\bf M}^n =  {\bf E+(E-I)(D(E-I))}^n.$$

Hence, for instance, if the eigenvalues of $\bf D(E-I)$ all have modulus less than $1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\bf M}^n=\bf E$. In general

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}{\bf M}^n = {\bf E +(E-I)}\lim_{n\to \infty}{\bf (D(E-I))}^n.$$