# Prove $C(X^\mathrm{T}X+C^\mathrm{T}C)^{-1}C^\mathrm{T}= I$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, statistical-inference

Consider the linear model $Y = X \beta + \epsilon$, where $\beta \in \Bbb R^{p}$. Suppose that $r := \mbox{rank}(X) < p $ and let $C \in \Bbb R^{m\times p}$ be a matrix satisfying the condition

1. $\mbox{rank}(C) = p-r$,
2. $\mathcal{R}(X^\mathrm{T})\cap \mathcal{R}(C^\mathrm{T})=\{0\}$.

then

$$(X^\mathrm{T}X+C^\mathrm{T}C)^{-1} \text{ is a generalized inverse of } C^\mathrm{T}C \tag{a}$$

$$C(X^\mathrm{T}X+C^\mathrm{T}C)^{-1}C^\mathrm{T}=I \tag{b}$$

I think one can be obtained by another, since if
$C(X^\mathrm{T}X+C^\mathrm{T}C)^{-1}C^\mathrm{T}=I$, then
$C^\mathrm{T}C(X^\mathrm{T}X+C^\mathrm{T}C)^{-1}C^\mathrm{T}=C^\mathrm{T}I$, which implies $$C^\mathrm{T}C(X^\mathrm{T}X+C^\mathrm{T}C)^{-1}C^\mathrm{T}C=C^\mathrm{T}IC=C^\mathrm{T}C,$$ Hence we prove the (a). now I am not sure how to prove (b), thank you for help me to figure it out.

Comment: What are you calling a "**design** matrix" ? A boolean (0-1) matrix ?

Comment: What is your work on the subject ? Have you attempted to consider matrix $[X|C]$ ?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: The course of the linear model.

Comment: Yes, but which one?  Your question is about to be closed because people suspect you are attempting to cheat on your homework.

Comment: Thank you, this comes from an excercise of linear model text book.

Comment: You haven't answered me about the specificities of a "design matrix" ; this term has disappeared from your question...

Comment: just a matrix, which Xis N\times P, thank you.

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2669923

Comment: Thank you I am not understand this methods, does there any other approaches to prove ? thank you.